# How create a bootstrap grid with one column above and two below?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

My ask is: how can I transform a bootstrap grid with three columns on desktop version, in one column above and two below on mobile version?

I already tried a lot of things without success...

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried!

Comment: Now it's 1AM in Brazil, in the morning when I get to the office I can post the code... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in mobile screen `col-6` last two div and first is `col-12`, 
`col-xs-*` have been dropped in `Bootstrap 4` in favor of `col-*`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

Read more about [Bootstrap grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Answer (score 1):

it's for bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">Box 1</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Box 2</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Box1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Box2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Box3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

Bootstrap allows up to 12 columns in a page.

Here for XS devices like mobile phone, the button/widget should occupy all the 12 grids , so that there is only 1 button/widget in every row, hence `col-xs-12`.


Since the desktop can be a medium device, the 3 widget/button should span across the whole page, hence the value `col-md-4`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
  <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



 </body>
</html>
```

> Read More about bootstrap 4 grid system

[bootstrap 4 grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)